# Screenshots in Azure Pipelines Test Report from XCTEST Results (JUnit)

Tags: xcode, junit, azure-pipelines, report, xctest

Did somebody try to integrate the XCTest report (JUnit from XCODE) with Azure pipelines - with screenshots?
Actually, I have a test report published on Azure pipelines but I can not attach screenshots if the test fails. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.